# How to copy matched id DataGridView rows to another DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have three DataGridViews. Two on form3 and one on form1. I am trying to copy two form3 DataGridView rows of sameid to form1 DataGridView but my code is displaying only one row even if there are multiple rows in form3 DataGridView2.

```
    Dim x As String
    x = Form3.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    Dim i As Integer = (Form3.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1)
    Do While (i >= 0)
        i = (i - 1)
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Form3.DataGridView2.Rows
            If dr.Cells(0).Value = x Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value, dr.Cells(3).Value, dr.Cells(4).Value)
            End If
        Next
    Loop
```

Comment: How did you fill DataGridView1? Is the DataSource set to a DataTable. Work with the DataTable.

Comment: There is not enough code and context to provide a complete response. But a more clever way would be to a) work on the datasource (dataset/datatable etc), not the DGV and 2) use form events and let the target form refresh itself. Any variable, including a dataset can be passed with a custom event. I suggest you have a look here for example: [VB.NET: Windows Forms Custom delegates and events](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53470.vb-net-windows-forms-custom-delegates-and-events.aspx).

Comment: Also, you could also use a [DataView](http://vb.net-informations.com/dataview/filter-dataview.htm) to filter the data, and pass the DataView to the target form as a datasource for the other DGV.

Comment: As mentioned already by Anonymous, there is insufficient information to provide a quality response. It does appear there is no data source for either DataGridView. Consider using a BindingSource and DataTable for both DataGridView controls and in the child have a public property of IReadOnlyList(Of DataRow) that the other form has access to but can not modify as it Immutable. If you do not understand using a BindingSource or IReadOnlyList consider learning about them. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am adding rows to DataGridView through table and table is getting data from textboxes and trying to get matching rows in second DataGridView with Id.